# What happens when visible light transitions to invisible light?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, vision

I was just wondering what happens when you see a visible light, for example violet, and that light slowly increases/decreases until it's not visible to the human eye. Will it fade or just become instantly invisible? Could it even injure and cause blindness?

Comment: Welcome! Saying that the "*light slowly increases/decreases*" can mean two different things: a gradual change of the light's *intensity* or of its *wavelength*. Both such processes can *appear* to be the same but are physically quite different.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it fade or just become instantly invisible?

It will fade out as its wavelength gets further from the peak sensitivity wavelength of the eye (or of a specific photoreceptor in the eye).

> Could it even injure and cause blindness?

Yes, light at invisible wavelengths can cause injuries or blindness.

Comment: Sunburn might be the most common example of invisible wavelengths (ultraviolet) causing injury.

Answer (score 0):

It will fade in or out and a good example can be seen when you slowly heat something up until it starts to radiate from inferred to red visible light.